# How to determine which question/answer was deleted?

Tags: support

I have noticed a loss in my reputation and I think it should be related to some user who has deleted his question with my answer, or maybe his account altogether. Are there any means to determine what was this deleted answer? I would like if possible to have its text for myself in case one asks something similar (or at least the title of the question - to avoid unsuccessful search over my past responses).

Comment: (1) A user cannot delete their question with an *upvoted* answer. (2) When a user deletes their account, their votes are deleted too (which may result in a drop of other users' reputation), but their posts remain. (3) I don't see any  negative changes on your reputation timeline for the last 3 days. (4) See also: [Poster deletes question with valid answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182556/)

Comment: @40votes Just a few minutes ago I had 9576 on the meta tab and 9526 on the main tab (now I have 9526 on two). And I remember to have 9556 yesterday.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/423004) was removed. Evidently you had 5 upvotes before it was made wiki.

Comment: @robjohn It says "page not found"...

Comment: @O.L.: you need 10K rep [to see deleted questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). It is titled "Really needed some higher level maths"

Comment: Enter id = 423004 in [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/124313/post-with-its-answers-by-id) to get the question and all answers.

Comment: @40votes Thanks! So is it deleted or made wiki?

Comment: @O.L. The wiki mode did not make much difference here; you keep the points from upvotes that were given before the conversion to wiki. What happened is that the question got closed, and since it was closed and negatively scored, 20K users could vote to delete it at once. See [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:gGYtJXfbLKAJ:math.stackexchange.com/questions/423004/really-needed-some-higher-level-maths+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).

Comment: If you have enough points, you can vote to undelete the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, that answer is not particularly precious for me - but initially I didn't even know what has disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently deleted posts can usually be downloaded using Data Explorer, provided that the latest data dump took place after the creation of the post but before its deletion.

- Use [Post with its answers, by Id](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/124313/post-with-its-answers-by-id) if you know the Id of the deleted question. Since the Id is a part of the question's URL, it may be found in the history of your browser.
- Alternatively, use the query [My posts in reverse chronological order](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/124865/my-posts-in-reverse-chronological-order).  It will return all your posts present in the current data dump, with all associated data.

Also, a Google search for title or fragment of the post with the parameter `site:math.stackexchange.com` will usually lead to the cached version of the post.

If it's   **your question**  that gets deleted, finding it is easy: go to your `user profile` -> `questions` -> `deleted recent questions` at the bottom. You don't need 10K to see  your own deleted questions.